# How do you synchornize Fortify report with updated source code?

Tags: fortify, line-numbers

My project's source files have changed since the last Fortify scan was made. The Audit Workbench shows issues using the new source files causing a mismatch.
This mismatch even persists after I run scan again for the Fortify project.
It seems that the only way to re-align reported issues to correct source code is to perform the scan in a new Fortify project.
But this is not desirable since I will have to re-audit all the issues that have been audited in the original project.

Is there a way to get Fortify to re-assign the line numbers for stored issues to match the changes made in the source files?

Comment: Are you creating .fpr files for each scan? Typically, a user will scan the code and then output the scan results in a .fpr file before auditing so that the .fpr file is tied to the version of code that was scanned. From the .fpr, you can perform audits and generate report in the Audit Workbench.

Comment: I am hoping to avoid this. Ideally, I would scan one, create .fpr, audit, fix issues, scan again on the same project, and that should, ideally, merge the two scans into the same fpr so we can see that fixes applied indeed removed the issues reported...

Comment: I ran across your post while trying to figure out how to open the source code tab / Project Summary panel. My post is somewhat related (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141881/why-fortify-audit-workbench-source-editor-is-not-opening). I figured, you may know how to force open the source code tab / Project Summary panel. Also, contributors to this post (@p4r1, @adaj21, @SBurris), if you could suggest any fix, that would be fantastic. Thank a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things going on here.

1) When you open an FPR, Audit Workbench will look on the current hard drive to see if the source code resides on it (it knows the absolute file paths of the code that was scanned).  If it finds source code, it will use that to display when an issue is selected instead of using the source code it has inside of the FPR (I assume because of performance).

Since you have modified the source code after the scan, what you need to do is select `Tools -> Extract Source Code...` from the menu and extract the source code to a temporary location (you can delete it later).  When this happens, Audit Workbench will then use that code for display in Audit Workbench.

2) You mentioned having to re-audit issues when you scan again.  When you have your new scan open in Audit Workbench select `Tools -> Merge Audit Projects...` from the menu.  Then select your audited FPR file.

This will merge the two FPRs together and carryover previous comments and audit tags for issues that exist in both FPRs.