# Why Fortify Audit Workbench Source Editor is not opening?

Tags: fortify, workbench

I am using Fortify Audit Workbench 18.20.1071 to do analysis on already created Fortify projects. The Fortify projects (extension .fpr) were created using standard Fortify commands. The discovered code issues, are listed on the left pane, and are grouped by categories, depending on a predefined view. When clicking on those issues, I was previously able to see the code in the source code panel/viewer/editor (separate panel to the center-right). For some reason I am not able to open that panel anymore. I don't recall changing anything in the settings, but I'm not able to see the associated code anymore.

If I create a pdf Developer Workbook report, from the Fortify project, I am able to see the source code (in the pdf file), therefore I know that the source code is available. I assume it's just some Audit Workbench settings that I need to change, but I don't know which ones.

There is no code associated with my question, as it is related to the functionality of the Audit Workbench application.

What I expect to see is the following: When I click on a listed issue on the left pane, the source code file associated with the flagged issue should open on the pane to the center-right.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using ver 19.10 and here's how I got the source code tab to show again.

1. Reset the config (options/options/audit configuration/reset interface)
2. Reboot computer
3. Open audit workbench and reload project

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work. Do you happen to know how to force open source code tab if it's not opening automatically?